# Help to understand Chapter

Tags: chapters, titlesec

In a chapter heading, there are four main elements.

1. "Chapter" word
2. chapter no <1,2...>
3. "An unnecessary long and complicated chapter title"
4. optional graphics like box, circle etc in the background.

Now I want to know that **separately** for all elements how to change position, font, colour, size (all formatting) for the first three elements with gap between two line for the third element. And overall packing.

A sample code is given, however, I'm unable to control/set elements, because I didn't understand.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\Large\raggedleft}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
\rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.5cm} {\thechapter}\rule{5cm}{1.5cm}}}
{10pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
```

I prefer `\documentclass{book}`.

Comment: Did you check teh `titlesec` manual? It explains how it works.

Comment: may be too complex for me, with very few examples.

Comment: You could also just play around with the code to see what different parts are doing. For example, change `\Huge`  to `\tiny`.

Comment: What exactly is the question you are having?

Comment: from the code I understood `\chaptertitlename` is for "Chapter" word. But,`\thechapter` is for the title? Suppose I declare: `\definecolor{Nblack}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\newfontfamily\chapterfont[Color=Nblack,Scale=1]{Arial}`. Then `{\chapterfont{\thechapter}}` should change the font, but not happening. In addition with this, how to control format of chapter no <1,2...> ....

Comment: `\thechapter` prints the value of counter `chapter` (number).  If you use the chapter font around `\thechapter` it should change the number.

Comment: `\thechapter` typesets the formatted chapter number. If you want to change the numbering, you have to redefine `\thechapter`. Right now, you question is completely unclear to me. Why don't you say (a draw a pic by hand) in the question what you want and somebody can implement it for you.

Comment: @TeXnician which command control the element 3, i.e, the title of the chapter

Comment: @TeXnician @Johannes_B I got the element 1, 2, 4. Currently, to change the format of the title of the chapter without effecting other elements, I'm using `\chapter{\chapterfont{Introduction}}`. Is there anyway, so that I don't have to write `\chapterfont` every time.

Comment: I do not know exactly, but if you put it right after the `\Huge` it could work.

Comment: @TeXnician this is the ans. I tried every other block except this... :(

Comment: *"For example, change \Huge to \tiny"* ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve your problem it would be easiest to read the documentation of [`titlesec`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf). From that document:

> `\titleformat{〈command〉}[〈shape〉]{〈format〉}{〈label〉}{〈sep〉}{〈before-code〉}[〈after-code〉]`
>
> Here
>
> - 〈command〉 is the sectioning command to be redefined, i. e., \part, \chapter, \section, \subsection, \subsubsection, \paragraph or
>     \subparagraph. [...]
> - 〈format〉is the format to be applied to the whole title—label and text. This part can contain vertical material (and horizontal with
>     some shapes) which is typeset just after the space above the title.
> - The label is defined in 〈label〉. You may leave it empty if there is no section label at that level, but this is not recommended because by
>     doing so the number is not suppressed in the table of contents and
>     running heads.
> - 〈sep〉is the horizontal separation between label and title body and must be a length (it must not be empty). This space is vertical in
>     display shape; in frame it is the distance from text to frame. Both
>     〈label〉 and 〈sep〉are ignored in starred versions of sectioning
>     commands. If you are using picture and the like, set this parameter to
>     0 pt.
> - 〈before-code〉is code preceding the title body. The very last command can take an argument, which is the title text. However, with the
>     package option explicit the title must be given explicitly with #1
>     (see below).
> - 〈after-code〉 is code following the title body. The typeset material is in vertical mode with hang, block and display; in horizontal mode
>     with runin and leftmargin [...]. Otherwise is ignored.

This means your code changes `\chapter` to the `display` shape (label in separate paragraph). Your whole title (Chapter ...: NAME) is `\Large` and `\raggedleft`. The chapter label then is made uppercase (CHAPTER) and `\rlap`ped you have the chapter number with a rule. Between "Chapter" and "NAME" you have `10pt` distance. Finally you apply `\Huge` to "NAME" (the chapter title). Here you could apply your title font setting.