# Left aligned titles by titlesec

Tags: titlesec

I am trying to use package `titlesec` to left-align all my sections and subsections. I don't need to change anything else. I was trying two commands: `\titleformat{<command>}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}[<after-code>]` and `\titlespacing{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}`, which are somehow explained on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Sections_and_chapters) but I can't make it working. I thought if I skip the parameters, `titlesec` would provide the default values but what I really get error. `\titlespacing` does not work, either.

```latex
\titlespacing{\thesubsection\raggedright}{}{}{}
```

```latex
\titleformat{\thesection}[]{}{\thesection}{}{}[\raggedright]
```

Obviously, I did try to read a manual on CTAN but I don't understand it. The difficulty for me is I can't find information on how the commands are defined by default, so that I could only change on thing. If I skip anything, I get errors but I don't know what is the "default".

Thanks.

---

EDIT.
Below is a MWE. What happens is `Aaaaaaa bbbbbbbb and ccccccc dddd` (my apology I don't know the term) is very oddly looking and spread with long spaces. I would like to either avoid it by left-aligning the (sub)section.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{MWE}
\author{Test of the \texttt{titlesec}}
\date{}

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \subsection{Aaaaaaa bbbbbbbb and ccccccc dddd}
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

---

EDIT 2.

For the time being I just added two lines of code:

```latex
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\raggedright}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\raggedright}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

I am not answering this question because I don't know how to sorted out if `titlesec` is not used.

Thanks to Vincent for giving me a link to the documentation and the exact section number.

There is also [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364680/help-to-understand-chapter) for using this command in general.

Comment: Could you post a *complete* code of what you tried?

Comment: The default values are given on section 9.2 of `titlesec`'s [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), on page 24. However, if I understand your question correctly, you're trying to left align the text in all sections of your document? Why would you use `titlesec` for that?

Comment: @Vincent i am already using titlesec. It’s a template that includes this package, that’s why asked about titlesec. If i can do that otherwise, i’ll be happy to know. And thanks for pointing out the page i should read.

Comment: Thanks for the question and the answer. Saved my day.